# Is there a music player for linux that can sort based on multiple tags at the same time, including ID3v2 Date/TYER tag?

Tags: linux, music

I'm looking for a music player on linux that can replicate foobar2000's sort functionality.

I want to be able to sort my playlist by: Artist, then by Date/TYER, then by Track nr.

So far I tried Rhythmbox, Clementine, Guayadeque & Banshee. None seem to offer the ability to sort by multiple tags at a time, and none can read the ID3v2 TYER/Date tag which I keep in a YYYYMMDD format. They all display the ID3v1 YYYY tag, even though it looks like they can find other ID3v2 tags.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to find a player by myself in the end: Quod Libet

The ubuntu software center lists https://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/ as the developer website. But it looks like current development is done at https://github.com/quodlibet/quodlibet

It has a 'custom sort' option when you right click on your playlist and hide the first dropdown somehow (looks a little buggy here). You can add any combination of tags in the desired order.

Answer (score 0):

As of v2.8.0 (Build Date: Apr 16 2016), Amarok also doesn't support ID3v2 custom tags. Foobnix, which I believe comes by default with Ubuntu, doesn't support ID3v2 either.

An actively developed music player that does support ID3v2 and can successfully read custom tags written by Foobar2000 is [DeaDBeeF](http://deadbeef.sourceforge.net/download.html).

[image: DeaDBeeF supports ID3v2]

You can also simply run Foobar2000 with [Wine](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu): `wine foobar2000.exe`:

[image: Foobar2000 on Wine]

It has much better support for tagging: apply the same set of tags to multiple files, filter by tags (e.g. "UNDISTURBING > 70%" if you want to study, or "ACTIVE > 75%" for working out).